# How to write redirection rule using regex in lighttpd server

Tags: lighttpd

I have my files hosted in `192.168.1.1`.

Let's say `192.168.1.1/about` is a page  and I want to replace `192.168.1.1` with `newserver.com/about`

How to write a redirect for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To serve content for a domain (in your case `newserver.com`) you need add a A-record in DNS pointing to your server (`192.168.1.1`). If this is a local network only, add it to your local dns-server or to the hosts-files on the single machines.

If the served content for both the IP and the domain should be the same, you need to do nothing. Otherwise you can set a different document root:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "newserver.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/servers/newserver.com/" 
}
```

Then you can add a redirect

```
$HTTP["host"] == "192.168.1.1" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://newserver.com/$1" )
}
```

Also have a look at lighttpd's [documentation](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/TutorialConfiguration)